# MySQL prioritise row if exists, if not show something else

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have 2 tables, table 1 contains 1 record for every day, and table to contains multiple records for each day, like this.

**Table 1**

```
id | date      | number
1 | 01/01/2018 | 14
2 | 02/01/2018 | 2
3 | 03/01/2018 | 82
4 | 04/01/2018 | 61
```

**Table 2**

```
id | name      | number | winner | username
1 | 01/01/2018 | 1      | 0      | Joe Bloggs
2 | 01/01/2018 | 2      | 0      | Jim Bloggs
3 | 01/01/2018 | 3      | 0      | Sarah Bloggs
4 | 01/01/2018 | 4      | 0      | David Bloggs
5 | 01/01/2018 | 5      | 0      | Sam Bloggs
6 | 02/01/2018 | 1      | 0      | Mark Bloggs
7 | 02/01/2018 | 2      | 1      | Phil Bloggs
8 | 02/01/2018 | 3      | 0      | Steve Bloggs
9 | 03/01/2018 | 1      | 0      | Ben Bloggs
10| 03/01/2018 | 2      | 0      | Bill Bloggs
```

Whenever a user enters the draw, they are given a number. If that number matches the number for the date they are playing in table 1, they win, else they loose. The username and number they entered with is then entered into table 2 so we have a record of everyone who played.

I need to be able to get a list of all winners (1 for each day) but if there is no winner, show the date row but show 'no winner' instead.

So ideally from the above data, my result will look like this

```
id | date      | winner | username
1 | 01/01/2018 | 0      | No Winner
2 | 02/01/2018 | 1      | Joe Bloggs
3 | 03/01/2018 | 0      | No Winner
```

What is the best way to join table 2 on table 1, and prioritise the winning rows, else show 'no winner'?

Comment: What is the source of the username in the output, and to what do each of the `number` columns correspond?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple left join should work here:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.date,
    COALESCE(t2.winner, 0) AS winner,
    COALESCE(t2.username, 'No Winner') AS username
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date AND t2.winner = 1
ORDER BY
    t1.date;
```

[image]

### Demo

This answer assumes that there would only ever be at most one single winner on a given date.  It works because we can determine the presence of no winner by there being a `NULL` value on the corresponding columns coming from the second table, which would have happened if the join condition failed.